# How to combine rows from two tables into a single table based on Foreign key, in MySQL.?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables in MySQL as shown below:

```
+------+-------+------------------+
| ID   | Q_ID  |Question          |
+------+-------+------------------+
|1     | 1     |Colors in Rainbow |
|2     | 2     |Colors in Tree    |
+------+-------+------------------+


+------+-------+--------+
| ID   | Q_ID  |Answer  |
+------+-------+--------+
|1     | 1     |Violet  |
|2     | 1     |Blue    |
|3     | 1     |Yellow  |
|4     | 2     |Brown   |
|5     | 2     |Orange  |
|6     | 2     |Green   |
+------+-------+--------+
```

**Q_Id** is the field linking the two tables.
Each Q_id has **exactly 3 options** as answers.

Now, I want to write a query in MySQL that gives **the following table as output**.

```
+------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Q_ID | Question           |Answer 1  |Answer 2  |Answer 3  |
+------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1    | Colors in Rainbow  |Violet    |Blue      |Yellow    |
| 2    | Colors in Tree     |Brown     |Orange    |Green     |
+------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

How do I do that.?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I agree with your philosophy. But this is a case where simultaneous processing by many concurrent users would have put lot of stress on the web server.. By creating a view like this, it becomes a matter of running a simple `SELECT` statement.. That is why I was looking for a SQL solution..

Comment: I don't follow your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use subqueries with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

```
SELECT t1.q_id,
       (SELECT t2.answer
               FROM elbat2 t2
               WHERE t2.q_id = t1.q_id
               ORDER BY t2.id
               LIMIT 1
               OFFSET 0) answer1,
       (SELECT t2.answer
               FROM elbat2 t2
               WHERE t2.q_id = t1.q_id
               ORDER BY t2.id
               LIMIT 1
               OFFSET 1) answer2,
       (SELECT t2.answer
               FROM elbat2 t2
               WHERE t2.q_id = t1.q_id
               ORDER BY t2.id
               LIMIT 1
               OFFSET 2) answer3
       FROM elbat1 t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=9086c7b8ea99ac2397d914d7d670c777)
Note that you need some column(s) to `ORDER BY` here as otherwise there is no guaranteed order which could lead to some answer show up more than once or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all of the cases then you can use simple `CASE WHEN` and `MAX` combination here.

[Working Solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51da56c0e9da851288473b6d69deec9f)

```
SELECT Q_ID ,QUESTION,
MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(ID,3)=1 THEN ANSWER END) AS ANS1,
MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(ID,3)=2 THEN ANSWER END) AS ANS2,
MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(ID,3)=0 THEN ANSWER END) AS ANS3
 FROM
(WITH TAB1 AS 
(
SELECT 1 AS ID,        1 AS Q_ID ,     'Colors in Rainbow' AS QUESTION UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID,        2 AS Q_ID ,     'Colors in Tree'    AS QUESTION
),
TAB2 AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID ,     1 AS Q_ID, 'Violet' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID ,     1 AS Q_ID, 'Blue  ' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID ,     1 AS Q_ID, 'Yellow' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID ,     2 AS Q_ID, 'Brown ' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS ID ,     2 AS Q_ID, 'Orange' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS ID ,     2 AS Q_ID, 'Green ' AS ANSWER 
)
SELECT TAB2.ID,TAB1.Q_ID,TAB1.QUESTION,TAB2.ANSWER FROM TAB1 INNER JOIN TAB2 ON TAB2.Q_ID=TAB1.Q_ID 
) A
GROUP BY Q_ID ,QUESTION
```

***Edit:***

As stickybit said there is a flaw in my first answer. For getting rid of this flaw i used `ROW_NUMBER`. This edit made by guidance that come from stickybit. Thank you for your advice. (Window functions are work only mysql version 8.0 or above.)

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

```
SELECT Q_ID ,QUESTION,
MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(RN,3)=1 THEN ANSWER END) AS ANS1,
MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(RN,3)=2 THEN ANSWER END) AS ANS2,
MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(RN,3)=0 THEN ANSWER END) AS ANS3
 FROM
(WITH TAB1 AS 
(
SELECT 1 AS ID,        1 AS Q_ID ,     'Colors in Rainbow' AS QUESTION UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID,        2 AS Q_ID ,     'Colors in Tree'    AS QUESTION
),
TAB2 AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID ,     1 AS Q_ID, 'Violet' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID ,     1 AS Q_ID, 'Blue' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS ID ,     1 AS Q_ID, 'Yellow' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS ID ,     2 AS Q_ID, 'Brown' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 13 AS ID ,     2 AS Q_ID, 'Orange' AS ANSWER UNION ALL
SELECT 16 AS ID ,     2 AS Q_ID, 'Green' AS ANSWER 
)
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY TAB1.Q_ID ORDER BY TAB2.ID) as rn, TAB2.ID,TAB1.Q_ID,TAB1.QUESTION,TAB2.ANSWER FROM TAB1 INNER JOIN TAB2 ON TAB2.Q_ID=TAB1.Q_ID 
) A
GROUP BY Q_ID ,QUESTION
```

[image]

Comment: That would require the IDs to be continuous. If that condition fails the query may produce false results.

Comment: Why dear sir? Let us say there is another ID with value of 18 and Q_ID value of 2 that would be another answer like answer4 and another case. I do not think it would spoil my answer. @stickybit

Comment: Because you use `mod()` to determine the position. Two (or more) IDs can have the same modulo (and that also follows that a modulo might not appear at all). Here's an example how that fails: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f46c13f9759b141c5a8c8a19f41ba08

Comment: I did not think sequential. Now i get it. Thank you @stickybit

Comment: In MySQL 8 you maybe could rectify this, if you didn't take the modulo directly from the ID but used `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY q_id ORDER BY id)` instead of the ID for `mod()`. If that can be combined in a correct way with the aggregation. (It probably needs some derived table(s)).

Comment: Thank you again @stickybit . Learning from my mistakes tastes good too :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `group_concat()` in the table `answers` to concat the answers in the correct order and then join to `questions` where you use `substring_index()` to split:

```
select q.q_id, q.question,
       substring_index(all_answers, ',', 1) Answer1,
       substring_index(substring_index(all_answers, ',', -2), ',', 1) Answer2,
       substring_index(all_answers, ',', -1) Answer3
from questions q inner join (
  select q_id, group_concat(answer order by id) all_answers
  from answers 
  group by q_id
) a
on a.q_id = q.q_id
```

I use `','` as the separator for the concatenated answers.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uq3fMnNbrF5VLRTQ2cu9AE/0).

If there is a case that `','` could exist inside an answer then you can change it to any other character, by adding say `separator '@'` in `group_concat()` and using `'@'` in `substring_index()`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uq3fMnNbrF5VLRTQ2cu9AE/2).

Results:

```
| q_id | question          | Answer1 | Answer2 | Answer3 |
| ---- | ----------------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 1    | Colors in Rainbow | Violet  | Blue    | Yellow  |
| 2    | Colors in Tree    | Brown   | Orange  | Green   |
```